# Link XML and XSD using java

Tags: java, xml, xsd, marshalling

i'm trying to write the header for an xml file so it would be something like this:

```
<file xmlns="http://my_namespace"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://my_namespace file.xsd">
```

however, I can't seem to find how to do it using the Document class in java. This is what I have:

```
public void exportToXML() {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder;

        try {

            dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.newDocument();
            doc.setXmlStandalone(true);
            doc.createTextNode("<file xmlns=\"http://my_namespace"\n" +
                    "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"\n" +
                    "xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://my_namespace file.xsd\">");
            Element mainRootElement = doc.createElement("MainRootElement");
            doc.appendChild(mainRootElement);

            for(int i = 0; i < tipoDadosParaExportar.length; i++) {
                mainRootElement.appendChild(criarFilhos(doc, tipoDadosParaExportar[i]));
            }
            Transformer tr = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            tr.transform(new DOMSource(doc),
                    new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(filename)));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I tried writing it on the file using the createTextNode but it didn't work either, it only writes the version before showing the elements.

[PrintStartXMLFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJEKk.png)

Would appreciate if you could help me. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Your `createTextNode()` method is only suitable for creating text nodes, it's not suitable for creating elements. You need to use createElement() for this. If you're doing this by building a tree, then you need to build nodes, you can't write lexical markup.

I'm not sure what `MainRootElement` is supposed to be; you've only given a fragment of your desired output so it's hard to tell.

Creating a DOM tree and then serializing it is a pretty laborious way of constructing an XML file. Using something like an `XMLEventWriter` is easier. But to be honest, I got frustrated by all the existing approaches and wrote a new library for the purpose as part of Saxon 10. It's called simply "Push", and looks something like this:

```
Processor proc = new Processor();
Serializer serializer = proc.newSerializer(new File(fileName));
Push push = proc.newPush(serializer);
Document doc = push.document(true);
doc.setDefaultNamespace("http://my_namespace");
Element root = doc.element("root")
  .attribute(new QName("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "schemaLocation"), 
             "http://my_namespace file.xsd");
doc.close();
```